# Matplot lib line plot legend shows wrong color code for the lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The mat plot lib gives legend of line graph, but the color doesn't match. Here is a code to illustrate the issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math

d = {'Training': [270,180,160,150,135,130,120,110,100,95],'Validation': [290,220,200,180,170,173,175,185,188,195]
    ,'Validation Lr Drecay': [290,220,200,180,170,170,168,166,170,175]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot( )

plt.plot(df)

new_list = range(1,10)

plt.xticks(new_list)
#plt.yticks(range(1,5) * 10 + 100)
plt.grid()
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution. Remove `plt.plot(df)`.

It occurs because `df.plot()` makes plot with blue, orange, and green colors with legend, but plt.plot(df) makes new plot with other colors without legend.

Comment: That doesnt help with matplotlib features like grid

Answer (score 0):

Gilseung Ahn’s solution is fast way. another solution is: delete `df.plot()` and `plt.plot(df)`, then add these lines to your code:

```
plt.plot(df['Training'])
plt.plot(df['Validation'])
plt.plot(df['Validation Lr Drecay'])
```